# How to increase a static timestamp value for each call

Tags: python, locust

in my Locust script (Python) I decalre these two values in the start of the script:

```
from_date = "2023-07-01T08:00:00.000Z"
to_date = "2023-07-01T08:15:00.000Z"
```

Later in the script I use the values like this:

```
class SaveValuesUser(HttpUser):
host = server_name
# wait_time = between(10, 15)

@task
def save_list_values(self):
    data_list = []

    for i, (ts_id, ts_value) in enumerate(TS_IDs.items()):
        if i > 31:
            break

        data = get_data(ts_id, from_date, to_date, ts_value)
        data_list.append(data)
        
    json_data = json.dumps(data_list, indent=2)
    self.save_values(json_data)

def save_values(self, json_data):
    print(type(json_data))
    print(json_data)
    # Make the PUT request with authentication:
    response = self.client.put("/api/SaveValues", data=json_data, headers=headers)
    # Check the response:
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("SaveValues successful!")
        print("Response:", response.json())
    else:
        print("SaveValues failed.")
        print("Response:", response.text)
```

Is there a way to have allways increasing (and unique) timestamp values for each increment in the for loop?

Can I use i.e. the iterator to increase the timestamps to i.e.

```
 from_date = "2023-07-02T08:00:00.000Z"
 to_date = "2023-07-02T08:15:00.000Z"
```

here increase by one day. But might be a problem when I get to value 30.

I need valid timestamps that are unique and "higher" for each call

Comment: Don't work with strings, but with datetime object.

Comment: ok, but it has to be on the format (Zulu?): 2023-07-02T08:00:00.000Z

Comment: I suggest you approach this as ”regular” python problem. You’ll find hundreds of examples just a google search away.